# array subscript overloading in c++

Tags: c++, function, types

I'am a novice programmer. I have Problem with error: invalid types[int]' for array subscript. I can't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "D:\programyCodeBlocks\arytmetyka\include\CLiczba.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CLiczba a;
    CLiczba b;
    CLiczba wynik;
    a.vset("5");
    b.vset("5");
    cout << "calk: " << a.czescCalk[0] << endl;
    cout << "ulam: " << a.czescUlam[2] << endl;
    cout << "znak: " << a.znak << endl;
    wynik = a.cdodaj(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem appears in cout << "calk: " << a.czescCalk[0] <

```
#ifndef CLICZBA_H
#define CLICZBA_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CLiczba
{
    public:
    CLiczba();
    CLiczba(string liczba);
    virtual ~CLiczba();
    void vset(string liczba);
    CLiczba cdodaj(CLiczba liczba);
    CLiczba codejmij(CLiczba liczba);

    vector<int> czescCalk();
    vector<int> czescUlam();

    bool znak;
    int dlCalk;
    int dlUlam;
    protected:
    private:

 };

 #endif // CLICZBA_H
```

and

```
#include "D:\programyCodeBlocks\arytmetyka\include\CLiczba.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
//#include <string>

CLiczba::CLiczba()
{
    //dlCalk = 0;
    //dlUlam = 0;
    znak = true;
} // End CLiczba::CLiczba()

CLiczba::CLiczba(string liczba)
{
    //dlCalk = 0;
    //dlUlam = 0;
    znak = true;
    vset(liczba);
} //End CLiczba::CLiczba(string liczba)

void CLiczba::vset(string liczba)
{
    int pom = 0;
    if (liczba.at(0) == '-')
    {   
        znak = false;
        pom = 1;
    } //End  if (liczba.at(0) == '-'

    int pozPrzecinek = liczba.find(',');
    while(pom < pozPrzecinek)
    {
        czescCalk.push_back(liczba.at(pom) -48);
        //dlCalk++;
        pom++;
    } //End while(pom < pozPrzecinek)

    pom++;
    while(pom < liczba.length())
    {
        czescUlam.push_back(liczba.at(pom) -48);
        //dlUlam++;
        pom++;
    } //End while(pom < liczba.length())

} //End void CLiczba::vset(string liczba)
```

Comment: Could you please translate the relevant parts of the source code?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `czescCalk` to be a method? Or should that just be a `vector<int>` member?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I forgot about it.
Liczba - Number
wynik - result
czescCalk - total part
czescUlam - fractional part
znak - sign

Comment: @user2948135 What Stefano was indicating was to write your code in English. All of it. Not just to give us some translations. It will help us understand what the code is supposed to do, and will be of great benefit to you in your career (should be be looking to pursue one). But from your code I'm assuming you want czescCalk to be a vector in which case it should be `vector<int> czescCalk;` and not `vector<int> czescCalk();` as you have now.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I thought that vector<int> czescCalk(); is a empty constructor. Now it works.

Comment: It was my first post on this website. Can I thank you in official way? Or it isn't neceserry?

Comment: You can upvote answers that helped you. Or you can even accept the answer that helped you most, by accepting it. Both are optional and entirely up to you, but of course always appreciated. You can find a visual explanation on the about page: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I am assuming you want `czescCalk` to be a `vector<int>`, rather than it being a method returning a `vector<int>`. In which case you should not write

```
vector<int> czescCalk();
vector<int> czescUlam();
```

but

```
vector<int> czescCalk;
vector<int> czescUlam;
```